# Let there be a connected graph $H$ and $p \in \mathbb N$. When are there $p$ spanning trees so that every edge is in at least one spanning tree?

Tags: graph-theory

Let there be a connected graph $H$ and $p \in \mathbb N$. When are there $p$ spanning trees so that every edge is in at least one spanning tree?

What is the condition that needs to be met in order for this to be fullfiled?

Any hints or leads will be more than welcomed!

---Rephrased!!!--- Thank you.

Comment: a spanning tree of a graph can contain all edges of a graph only and only if the graph is a tree itself

Comment: What doe you mean at least one tree contining all edges?

Comment: @sasha rephrased! Thank you.

Comment: @DarAdal I am not sure if I understood your question correctly but I have added an answer , hope it answers your question

Comment: I think the intent of the question is "For which graphs is it possible to find at most $p$ spanning trees such that each edge is in at least one spanning tree".  Does that sound right ?

Comment: @ManuelLafond as $p$ is any integer it would be true for any simple connected graph $H$ i guess

Comment: Well I guess the point is that $p$ is given, and OP needs to find the graphs for the given $p$.  For instance, can you characterize graphs that have $p = 2$ spanning trees covering all edges.  Then, can you characterize graphs for which $p = 3$ spanning trees suffice ?  And so on...

Comment: oh I see the point now thanks :)